# Changing a select input to a checkbox acting as an on/off toggle switch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I have a set of 7 dropdown inputs allowing admins to say whether they are open or closed for business on a given day. I'd like that changed to 7 open/closed switches (presumably styled checkboxes?) but can't figure out how to do this!

Here are the relevant bits of code I currently have (prior to any change):

**app/view/backend/inventory_pool/edit.html.haml**

```
- content_for :title, @inventory_pool
  = form_for [:backend, @inventory_pool], html: {name: "form"} do |f|

    .content
      - if is_admin?
        %a.button{:href => root_path}= _("Cancel")
      %button.button{:type => :submit}= _("Save %s") % _("Inventory Pool")

      %section
        %h2= _("Basic Information")
        .inner
          .field.text
            .key
              %h3= "#{_("Print Contracts")}"
              %p.description
            .value
              .input
                %input{type: "checkbox", name: "inventory_pool[print_contracts]", checked: @inventory_pool.print_contracts}


      %section#workdays
        %h2= _("Workdays")
        .inner
          - [1,2,3,4,5,6,0].each do |i|
            .field.text
              .key
                %h3= "#{I18n.t('date.day_names')[i]}"
              .value
                .input
                  %select{:name => "store[workday_attributes][workdays][]"}
                    %option{:label => _("Open"), :value => Workday::WORKDAYS[i]}= _("Open")
                    %option{:label => _("Closed"), :value => "", :selected => @store.workday.closed_days.include?(i) ? true : nil}= _("Closed")
```

**app/models/workday.rb**

```
class Workday < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :inventory_pool

  WORKDAYS = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"]

  def is_open_on?(date)

    return false if date.nil?

    case date.wday
    when 1 return monday
    when 2 return tuesday
    when 3 return wednesday
    when 4 return thursday
    when 5 return friday
    when 6 return saturday
    when 0 return sunday
    else
      return false #Should not be reached
    end
  end

  def closed_days
    days = []
    days << 0 unless sunday
    days << 1 unless monday
    days << 2 unless tuesday
    days << 3 unless wednesday
    days << 4 unless thursday
    days << 5 unless friday
    days << 6 unless saturday
    days
  end

  def workdays=(wdays)
    WORKDAYS.each {|workday| write_attribute(workday, wdays.include?(workday) ? true : false)}
  end
end
```

And in **app/controllers/backend/inventory_pools_controller** I have this (abridged):

```
  def update
    @inventory_pool ||= InventoryPool.find(params[:id])
    process_params params[:inventory_pool]
  end

  def process_params ip
    ip[:print_contracts] ||= "false" # unchecked checkboxes are *not* being sent
    ip[:workday_attributes][:workdays].delete "" if ip[:workday_attributes]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a pretty heavy change, but I've found the best way to do it is very similar to [Ryan Bates' Railscast on using a bitmask](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association).  This tutorial is awesome and is relatively quick to set up, and should map very easily from user roles (which is used in the tutorial) to days of the week on a `Workday` in your app.

Comment: Thanks. That was useful as I'm new to Ruby and Rails and wasn't familiar with the check_bog_tag syntax. I think I've worked it out now.

Comment: Awesome!  If this answer helped, please close the question by giving this answer a checkmark! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. In the haml, I had to replace:

```
            .input
              %select{:name => "store[workday_attributes][workdays][]"}
                %option{:label => _("Open"), :value => Workday::WORKDAYS[i]}= _("Open")
                %option{:label => _("Closed"), :value => "", :selected => @store.workday.closed_days.include?(i) ? true : nil}= _("Closed")
```

With:

```
        = check_box_tag "inventory_pool[workday_attributes][workdays][]", Workday::WORKDAYS[i], @inventory_pool.workday.closed_days.include?(i) ? nil : true
```